# posix thread in c: terminating 1 thread from another using by passing threads

Tags: c, multithreading, posix

So as i am practicing threads, i realize that we can pass values to threads. Now i am wondering, Can i pass thread to another when creating. Something like that;

```
int main(){
  pthread_t t1;
  pthread_t t2;

  pthread_create(&t1, NULL, counting, t2);
  pthread_create(&t2, NULL, waiting, &results);
//...
}
```

and my function looks like that;

```
void* counting(void * arg) {
    pthread_t *t = arg;
    pthread_cancel(arg);
}
```

I am doing it because from the `counting` thread i want to terminate the `waiting` thread when it is done.

Comment: Yes, you can pass a `pthread_t*` to a thread. Be aware that you need to synchronize access to shared data, even if it's a `pthread_t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues:

1) The value of `t2` is not set until your second call to `pthread_create` returns. You need to change the order of the two `pthread_create` calls.

2) Since the thread takes a `void *`, you need to pass it a `void *`. It's not safe to cast a `pthread_t` to a `void *`. A common pattern is to `malloc` new structure, fill it in, and pass a pointer to it to the newly-created thread. The newly-created thread can `free` the structure when it's done with it. (You could also cast `&t2` to a `void *`, just be sure that `t2` remains valid at all times because otherwise it's not safe to dereference the pointer you passed to the newly-created thread.)

With those two changes, it should work.

Comment: @Waqar Haider, Literally change the order of the statements, and use `&t2` instead of `t2` in the call to `pthread_create`. (Just make sure that `t1` completes before `main` completes by calling `pthread_join`.)